# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la url de la anotación @CrossOrigin dependiendo del ambiente utilizado?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yml

Tengo el siguiente metodo que recibe parametros de un front, localmente me funciona asi, pero como le puedo hacer para que tome una url diferente, que no sea localhost, dependiendo del ambiente donde monte mi applicacion(produccion, etc), como se puede hacer dinamicamente?

seria a traves de un yml? como seria?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consultarValores")
public class ValoresController {


@Autowired
private ValoresService valoresService;


@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> consultarValParam(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "inicio") String inicio,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "final") String final) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<?> listarVal = null;
    try {
         listarVal = valoresService.listarValores(inicio, final);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error ");
        throw e;
    }
    
    return listarVal;
}
```